# Laravel 5 Session Randomly Lost when redirected from payment gateway

Tags: php, laravel, session-cookies

I have a strange problem with a callback. I have a route called back by a payment provider and there are several strange things happening.

The same application on another server had none of these problems. There was a migration I made and all parameters are set the same, so configuration for Laravel and Php is identical but still randomly some customers don't have a session when they get redirected back by the provider.

I managed to handle the callbacks even without a session until I figure out the reason of this problem but the strange thing also happening is that the translations too of some blade / pdf that gets sent via mail are showing just as keys and not their value.

I have tried messing with the session.php config about samesite, lifetime, etc, even though the previous server didn't gave me any of these problems, with same values; but nothing helped.

Another thing I haven't tried is to set the web middleware to this route, but as I said I am trying to manipulate things that never were a problem.

php.ini

```
Session Support => enabled
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_samesite => no value => no value
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 0 => 0
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => /var/lib/php/sessions => /var/lib/php/sessions
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 5 => 5
session.sid_length => 26 => 26
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
session.trans_sid_hosts => no value => no value
session.trans_sid_tags => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form= => a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=
XDG_SESSION_TYPE => tty
XDG_SESSION_CLASS => user
XDG_SESSION_ID => 4663
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS => unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_TYPE'] => tty
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_CLASS'] => user
$_SERVER['XDG_SESSION_ID'] => 4663
$_SERVER['DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS'] => unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
```

config/session.php

```
...
'driver' => 'file',
'lifetime' => 1200,
'path' => '/',
'secure' => false,
'samesite' => null,
'expire_on_close' => false,
```

What could be the reason of this? What am I missing?

Comment: You should save your session.

Comment: What do you mean? Before sending to the provider? I never saved any session in this app and never lost it on redirects.

Comment: 'expire_on_close' => false,

Comment: my bad didn't include, but also that is set false

Comment: And this one? 'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

Comment: make sure you have the right permission on this server and the sessions are stored correctly. looks like the permission issue but you can also try storing the session in database with laravel.

Comment: I can see the sessions being stored. After I increased their lifetime I see a lot session  files still not closed / removed.

Comment: *randomly some customers* does it happen consistently for the same customers or could it work for some customers but then not work for those same customers later?

Comment: I checked the logs and I do have cases where the same customer was redirected back 8 minutes later and the session didn't expire. While the same customer after 3 minutes when returns back the session is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish a reliable communication, without relying on finding or understanding **what is messing with the session**, as so many things could have or will some day; I managed this in different ways,
but being in production adopted the third one, with the idea to switch to the second one when I am on more *calm waters*:

1. Set some middleware and it will ask user to login then redirected to the `confirmation route`
2. Set another pre-landing page where the customer confirms the operation then from your page redirect to the `confirmation route` and the session will be attached again
3. Resolve this internally without involving user interaction: when the `confirmation route` gets called by the provider, use some pre-exchange hashed keys so that when you get called back you use these keys to find who is the user connected to that payment, login that user and set whatever Session data you might need generally for the `confirmation route` to work. [**communication must be secure**]

The most important rule I've learned:

**Never expect a payment provider won't mess your session**

Hope these help someone else.